# Rogue Chrome process eating CPU

Tags: google-chrome

I have a rogue Chrome CPU process at 40% running 24/7.

Sysinternals Process explorer says the process has those super-shady command arguments. I can't trace back its origin.

`"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=1528,17667036987940741940,5497819695524880889,131072 --lang=en-US --disable-oor-cors --enable-auto-reload --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=9967693049173305802 --renderer-client-id=5 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --mojo-platform-channel-handle=2688 /prefetch:1`

I did the usual stuff with no success :

- Disabled all extensions
- Reinstalled Chrome and full wipe
- Disabled "Chrome running in background"
- Malware Bytes scan twice
- Process is not in Chrome's task manager
- Latest Windows 10 with Intel/Nvidia.
- No trace of the command in Registry

Is there a way to mitigate this problem ?

Comment: This question is all over the internet (same list in the same order) with little result. Uninstall Chrome completely, restart, do NOT install Chrome, and then check CPU in Task Manager. Obtain, install and run Autoruns (SysInternals) and see if the process above is starting without Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I suspect this is some kind of rare crypto-miner using an headless chrome.

Comment: congratulations and thanks for the question and the updates!
I have the same problem but I use Linux operating system in the Debian version, how can I use this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Epilogue: It was indeed a crypto-miner hidden inside of an headless chrome.

For anyone that has the same problem, the file was located in the following directory : `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_00002d`

Only Kaspersky detects the virus at the moment. Here's the VirusTotal [link](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/96ed1cd92251b0fb3fcc4c3d051d9759f25a89689c1d40224474f098b46ee40a/detection).

Deleting the file solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you open Chrome's own Task Manager it will tell you which tab(s) are using cpu

Either:

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

or

Open the three vertical dots "⋮" menu in the top right > More Tool > Task Manager

If Chrome's Task Manager doesn't show the CPU column then right click on one of the column headers and activate it from the menu.

---

If there aren't any high CPU tasks listed it could be to do with the `--field-trial-handle` parameter. See this page for how to disable field trials:

https://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/05/field-trials-in-chrome-how-to-randomize-or-force-them/

Specifically, you can start chrome using one of these parameters:

```
--disable-field-trial-config  —— Disables all field trial tests in fieldtrial_testing_config.json
--fake-variations-channel     —— Fakes the release channel of the browser for testing.
--force-fieldtrials           —— The option can be used to enforce certain field trials in Chrome. Requires knowledge of values.
--force-fieldtrial-params     —— The option can be used to force certain parameters but it is necessary to know valid values to use it.
--force-variation-ids         —— Enforces additional variation IDs.
--reset-variation-state       —— Forces a reset of all Chrome variation states.
--variations-override-country —— Overrides the country used for evaluating variations.
--variations-server-url       —— Specify a custom variation server.
```